# GLIBCXX_3.4.9 not found

Tags: gcc, glibc, libstdc++

I have a problem concerning `libstdc++.so`.

I installed a new version of gcc and tried to compile C++ code. The compiling worked, but when I try to execute the binary (`m5.opt` is its name) I've got the following error:

```
build/ALPHA_SE/m5.opt: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by build/ALPHA_SE/m5.opt).
```

Do I need to replace `libstdc++.so`? And if so, where can I download the version I want? On the GCC-website they say libstdc++ is a part of gcc now.

### Details

GCC:
I had gcc 4.1.2 before, but I downloaded gcc 4.2.4. From the untarred gcc-directory I executed `./configure`; make; sudo make install`.
When I tried to use gcc or g++ to compile, it's default version was still 4.1.2. To overcome this I replaced some links:

```
mv /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc_bak
ln -s /usr/local/bin/gcc gcc
mv /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++_bak
ln -s /usr/local/bin/g++ g++
```

GLIBC(++) -- libstdc++:

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.8
/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so -> libstdc++.so.6.0.9
/lib/libc.so.6 -> libc-2.5.so -> libc-2.5.so
```

Linux-version:
`uname -a` gives:

`Linux madmax 2.6.18-128.4.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 4 12:51:10 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is that you built your new `GCC` incorrectly: on Linux you should use

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

The default installation prefix is `/usr/local`, which is why `make install` put `gcc` and `g++` binaries into `/usr/local/bin`, etc.

What's happening to you now is that you compile and link using the new (symlinked) `GCC 4.2.4`, but at runtime your program binds to the old `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` (version 6.0.8, instead of required 6.0.9). You can confirm that by running `ldd build/ALPHA_SE/m5.opt`: you should see that it uses `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`.

There are several fixes you could do.

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64 ldd build/ALPHA_SE/m5.opt
```

should show you that setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is sufficient to redirect the binary to correct library, and

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib64 build/ALPHA_SE/m5.opt
```

should just run. You could "bake" this path into m5.opt binary by relinking it with `-Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib64`.

A more permanent solution is to fix the libraries the same way you fixed the binaries:

```
cd /usr/lib64 && mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6_bak &&
ln -s /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 .
```

An even better solution is to reconfigure the new `GCC` with `--prefix=/usr`, and then `make all install`.

Comment: Thanks! 
I still had some problems with make all install, so I removed the untarred gcc directory and started from scratch.
I ran "./configure --prefix=/usr", "make" and "sudo make install".
It's working now! Spaseeba!

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a very old question, but ...

It's not usually a good idea to replace the system compiler (i.e. the one in `/usr`) because the entire system will have been built with it and depend on it.

It's usually better to install the new compiler to a separate location and then see the libstdc++ FAQ [How do I insure that the dynamically linked library will be found?](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths) and [Finding Dynamic or Shared Libraries](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.dynamic) in the manual for how to ensure the correct libstdc++.so is found at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers here should be fine, but the 'quick and easy' solution if you do happen to have gcc installed to /usr/local/ is to just add the new libs to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib64
```

You can also check the to see if you have the right versions of GLIBC installed using

```
strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
strings /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.18 | grep GLIBC
```

I got this last tip from another forum so credits due where credits due!

Comment: You're right, it is not only safer, but simpler and faster