# GCC installation prefix under Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, installation, prefix

What is the recommended installation prefix for GCC under Linux (say default installation of Ubuntu)?
Would it be the default /usr/local of just /usr?

I am asking because I ran into a problem similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952146/glibcxx-3-4-9-not-found).

So, is it really a mistake (not recommended) to install GCC to /usr/local

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From official gcc instalation documents:

> --prefix=dirname
>   Specify the toplevel installation directory. This is the recommended way to install the tools into a directory other than the default. The toplevel installation directory defaults to /usr/local.
>
> We highly recommend against dirname being the same or a subdirectory of objdir or vice versa. If specifying a directory beneath a user's home directory tree, some shells will not expand dirname correctly if it contains the `~' metacharacter; use $HOME instead.

More at: http://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

Comment: As far as I know every user installation defaults to "/usr/local", but this is not just some application... I know that some people recommend [/usr](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/general/gcc.html)

Comment: @Petr: i answered to this part: `So, is it really a mistake (not recommended) to install GCC to /usr/local`. What is preferred dir i did not find any data on it. So I assume - it depends. GCC configuration is very wide so everything depends on what are you doing. I know my friend needed special params that C code would work with assembler code. So it all depends on project. If you don't want to rely all your system on same installation of GCC i suggest you to use virtual environment and use what ever options you need for the project your'e working on.

Comment: This is a somewhat incomplete answer - it will work for simple programs but eventually breakdown. For example it didn't compile the later [R](https://cran.r-project.org/) for me. Calling this local installation will use the system libraries and system gcc headers. You will need extra options when compiling, such as `-Wl,/your_prefix/lib/lib64` and `-L /your_prefix/lib64` to ensure your dynamic and static libraries are used. I'm still not sure of the best solution to this, I think `-B` is relevant too and perhaps I should do `-I`.